# How can I reference another class instance variable when getting or setting another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, getter-setter, instance-variables

Everyone says to use self.variable_name but that only works inside the method that gets or sets it. I need to be able to use the values of other variables set in the instance when setting one.

```
class WebSite:

    def __init__(self, url='', subdomain='www'):
        self.url = url
        self.subdomain = subdomain

    @property
    def url(self):
        return self.__url

    @url.setter
    def url(self, url):
        self.__url = f'http://{self.subdomain}.example.com'

    @property
    def subdomain(self):
        return self.__subdomain

    @subdomain.setter
    def subdomain(self, subdomain):
        self.__subdomain = subdomain
```

then:

```
>>>import package as p
>>>site = p.website()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/dblack/Code/package/package/website.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.url = url
  File "/Users/dblack/Code/package/package/website.py", line 13, in url
    self.__url = f'http://{self.subdomain}.site.com'
  File "/Users/dblack/Code/package/package/website.py", line 17, in subdomain
    return self.__subdomain
AttributeError: 'WebSite' object has no attribute '_WebSite__subdomain'
```

I tried a lot of finagling, this must be the wrong approach completely.

Comment: You need to initialize `self.subdomain` before `self.url`, given that `url`'s setter references `self.subdomain.  Note that `url`'s setter doesn't make much sense as it is: it completely ignores the parameter you give it!

Comment: You're right. This is a stripped down example, sorry!

Comment: Why are you using double-underscore name-mangling here??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i'm following a course https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php

Comment: @jasonharper you are correct! that solved this.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you... the use is that there is a default 'www' but the user can override it. `site = p.WebSite()` should create 
`site.url 
>>>http://www.example.com`
and `site = p.WebSite(subdomain='www3')` should create 
`site.url 
>>>http://www.example.com`

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible, but your code has inter-related dependencies. Setting the `url` property looks up `self.subdomain`, which calls the `subdomain` property which in turn looks up the value of `self.__subdomain` - which doesn't exist yet.

You should at least set `self.subdomain` first. However, you should reconsider having getters and setters for `subdomain` at all; just set the an attribute directly. Either way, you should avoid the double-underscore prefix, since this does name mangling and leads to behaviour you may not expect; if you must set a hidden attribute, use a single underscore prefix.

Answer (score 1):

A number of issues.

- You define a class member `url` as a property, *and* an instance member `url` as a variable. Instance members shadow class members at lookup.
- You access `.__url` instance member without creating it first, in the constructor.
- You define a trivial getter *and a trivial setter* for a private variable `.__url`. [It makes no sense](http://developers-club.com/posts/75661/). If you want a world-writable value, just use a variable; Python is not Java.

Comment: `.__url` isn't the issue, I believe it is `.__subdomain`.

Comment: It's still incorrect, and shows the lack of understanding of what's going on. I'd suggest to come up with the simplest design that could possibly work, make it work, and refine from there.

Comment: @9000 the amount of python i learned just from your comment cannot be understated. thank you!